# How does time period change with damping in oscillations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, oscillators, harmonics

I have had contradicting answers. My teacher has told me that time period increases with damping. It does make sense in a way because it's harder for the pendulum to move. Furthermore, previous answers I checked also confirm this.

But with the damping it's not just how hard it is for the pendulum to move, it is also how much it moves. The higher the damping the lower the amplitude for the pendulum. You can even see this mathematically using 2nd order diff. eq.
I have taken light damping in this case. Here is an example of a possible eq. [image]
If you use desmos or any other graphing calculator, the time period decreases over time.

Furthermore, a test I did also says time period decreases.
[image]  Q
The gist of the question is the air resistance doesn't affect the block and initially both are in phase with equal amplitude.
[image] MS

Comment: What's your question ?